# How to implement Bellman Ford algorithm using Python to find optimal data packet routing path?

Tags: python, routes, path, bellman-ford, optimal

The input data file is coordinates(nodes). The distances between them are calculated and matched against a table to find transmission rates. The goal is to find optimal routing path to either of 2 stations. That is,a path with maximum transmission rate while minimizing total number of links. What will be the code to implement Bellman Ford algorithm for this
? start nodes/vertices, links/edges, and transmission rates are stored as excel file.

```
    df = pd.read_csv ('Trans_rates_complete.csv')

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.edges = []

    def add_edge(self, u, v, weight):
        self.edges.append((u, v, weight))


class BellmanFord:
    def __init__(self, graph, source):
        self.graph = graph
        self.source = source
        self.distances = {vertex: float('inf') for vertex in graph.vertices}
        self.distances[source] = 0

    def run(self):
        for i in range(len(self.graph.vertices) - 1):
            for u, v, weight in self.graph.edges:
                if self.distances[u] + weight < self.distances[v]:
                    self.distances[v] = self.distances[u] + weight

        for u, v, weight in self.graph.edges:
            if self.distances[u] + weight < self.distances[v]:
                print("Negative cycle detected")
                return

        print("Shortest distances:", self.distances)

    def get_shortest_path(self, destination):
        path = []
        while destination != self.source:
            path.append(destination) 
            destination = self.predecessors[destination]
        path.append(self.source)
        return path[::-1]



i=0
vertices=[]
graph=[]
while i<len(df):
    vertices.append(df.start_car)
    u=df.start_car[i]
    v=df.end_car[i]
    weight=df.trans_rate[i]
    graph.append([u,v,weight])
    i=i+1
vertices.append('BS1')
vertices.append('BS2')
graph=Graph(vertices)
bf = BellmanFord(graph, 0)
bf.run()
print("Shortest path:", bf.get_shortest_path('BS1'))
```

Comment: Why not implement it as you have shown?

Comment: One is the error shown that distance[v] reads as float, where it needs to be integer to work. Changing to int(distance[v]) doesnt seem to solve the issue unfortunately.

Also, minimizing number of links - this objective is not taken into account here, is it? Sorry, I am quite new to python and this algorithm, hence the confusions.